# How to remove warning popups in Chromium Portable?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, chromium-portable

I have added a few flags in the Chromium Portable startup ini file such as these

```
-allow-file-access-from-files -disable-web-security -user-data-dir -ignore-certificate-errors
```

How do I remove the warning popups on startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add the following:

```
-test-type
```

It would prevent any warning popups.

Comment: I think it's --test-type